# xpath - search for number greater than and show parents

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I'm trying to get the facility enddate higher than `20170199` and it's parents, I've tried to get the parents with parent::* but it shows the whole tree instead of the filtered view.

Given XML

```
<Delivery>
   <Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>
     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20161231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20170231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
   </Person>
</Delivery>
```

What I've tried so far

```
<?php
$xmlStr = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
$res = $xmlStr->xpath("Person/Facility[EndDate>20170199]/parent::*");
echo '<pre>';print_r($res);
```

Expected result

```
   <Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>
     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20170231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
   </Person>
```

Actual result

```
   <Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>
     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20161231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20170231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
   </Person>
```

Comment: `20170299 ` - is invalid date, there's no such day or month `99`

Comment: There are no EndDate greater than `20170299` (that isn't a date as an aside, the last day in february 2017 is 28)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It is a 'date' but the notation of it is an integer so `20170299 + 1` makes `20170300`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte EndDate should be greater than `20170199` not `20170299` see the php code.

Comment: xml structure is invalid: ending tags for `EndDate` and `Delivery`. `<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest sorry my bad, see updated question. I've tested the code now so it should work for you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is filtering out/removing all `Facility` nodes which have child `EndDate` node with the value ***less than*** `20170199` (to retain the nodes with the value greater than `20170199`).

The solution using `DomDocument` and `DomXPath` classes:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
//$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->load("test.xml");

$person = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Person')->item(0);  // context node
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('Facility[EndDate <= 20170199]', $person) as $n) {
    $person->removeChild($n);
}    
echo $doc->saveXML($person);
```

The output:

```
<Person>
     <Name>John</Name>
     <LastName>Doe</LastName>

     <Facility>
       <TypeFacility>2</TypeFacility>
       <StartDate>20161131</StartDate>
       <EndDate>20170231</EndDate>
     </Facility>
   </Person>
```

---

[***DEMO link***](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68bd0334c59d90e54dc6e8b793ee61eb5005739e)

Comment: So it's not possible to get the expected result without filtering the XML?

Comment: @creativename, filtering, in this case, would be more straightforward, readable and managabble

Comment: Also not every person has an end date, can i filter on that too?

Comment: @FrankGroot, you have posted the input xml with one `Person`. The condition `not every person has an end date` - that's different case

Answer (score -1):

Using DOMDocument, I will do that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$personNodeList = $xp->query('//Person[Facility/EndDate > 20170131]');

$result = '';

foreach($personNodeList as $personNode) {
    $facilityNodeList = $xp->query('//Facility[EndDate <= 20170131]', $personNode);
    foreach ($facilityNodeList as $facilityNode) {
        $facilityNode->parentNode->removeChild($facilityNode);
    }
    $result .= $dom->saveXML($personNode);
}
```

In short: I select all Person nodes with at least one correct EndDate, and then I remove all Facility nodes with an incorrect EndDate.

Comment: pretty similar to mine. Besides, `loadXML` is for loading from a string, the OP has file

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: yes, except that it doesn't return an eventual Person node that has no correct EndDate. *(these one are filtered with the first query)*

Comment: I think this will produce invalid XML since it will append opening tags on the same line as closing tags. Why not just `$dom->saveXML()`?

Comment: @BobKruithof: where did you read that the goal is to produce XML?

Comment: Not talking about the goal. But since you are obviously trying to create some sort of result, I'm noting that it won't be valid XML.

Comment: @BobKruithof: once you have this kind of result, you are free to add a root element. "Noting that it won't be valid XML" here is uninteresting. You can also build an array with each node, it doesn't matter.

Comment: What you find uninteresting may in fact confuse others. And the fact that you create an invalid XML string and don't even do anything with that makes this a messy answer.